# Module not found when I tried to import pyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

My python version is 3.6. I am able to install the pyPDF2.
Ran pip install pyPDF2 successfully.

Ran pip list, it shows up as 1.26.0
[image]

My environment is not base, but I set up an environment as pytorch. pyPDF2 is installed successfully in this environment.

It pops error when I tried to import it. (typo fixed from the original post)
[image: (t]

Comment: What do you see if you run `python -m pip list`? Also, please edit your question to replace your screenshots with [markdown formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `import pyPDF` is incorrect. Instead try `import PyPDF2`.

Is also possible your `pip` does not match your `python` (this can be the case when multiple python versions are installed at the same time). Try running `python -m pip list` to confirm what exactly is installed.